# problema com submit

Tags: html, angularjs

Tenho o seguinte código em meu formulário:

```
<div class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-1-1">
        <button type="submit" class="md-btn md-btn-primary" ng-submit="frm.$valid && Salvar(registro2)">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quando clico em *submit*, tenho o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: this._recipeManager is null

Vejam na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O método `Salvar` não é chamado, alguém o motivo desse erro?

Aqui esta o início do meu formulário:

```
<form id="frm" class="uk-form-stacked">
```

função salvar do controller

```
  //salva ou altera registro no banco
$scope.Salvar = function (jsonTarefa) {
    $scope.progressbar.start();

    $scope.registro2.t0060_dt_agenda = document.getElementById('uk_dp_1').value;

    if ($scope.strStatus == 0)
        $scope.registro2.t0060_status = 0;

    jsonTarefa.t0031_id_pessoa = $scope.selected.t0031_id_pessoa;//seleciona o id_pessoa do select
    $http.post("/Tarefa/save", { jsonTarefa: jsonTarefa })
        .success(function (data) {
            if (data == "nosession")
                window.location.href = '#/forms/login';
            else if (data == "200") {
                $scope.getAllRegistro($scope.strPesquisa, 0);

                $scope.progressbar.complete();

                $scope.registro2 = {};
                $scope.frm.$setPristine();
                $scope.registro2.t0060_tipo = 1;
                $scope.registro2.t0060_status = 0;

            }
            else {
                UIkit.modal.alert('<div class=\'uk-text-center\'>' + data + '<br/><img id=\'img-erro\' class=\'uk-margin-top\' style=\'width: 18%;margin-bottom: -60px;\' src=\'assets/img/spinners/erro.png\' </div>', { labels: { 'Ok': 'OK' } });
                $scope.progressbar.complete();
            }
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            var str = "ERRO INESPERADO";
            $scope.sendMail(error, "Erro front end zulex");
            UIkit.modal.alert('<div class=\'uk-text-center\'>' + str + '<br/><img id=\'img-erro\' class=\'uk-margin-top\' style=\'width: 18%;margin-bottom: -60px;\' src=\'assets/img/spinners/erro.png\' </div>', { labels: { 'Ok': 'OK' } });
            $scope.progressbar.complete();
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A diretiva `ngSubmit` deve estar definida no formulário, não no botão, como você fez. Por isso ela não é chamada. O seu formulário deveria estar assim:

```
<form id="frm" class="uk-form-stacked" ng-submit="frm.$valid && Salvar(registro2)">
    [...]
    <button type="submit" class="md-btn md-btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Isso deve resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Celsom, o erro continua, na verdade o codigo estava como vc disse, eu fiz um teste, e acabei copiando o codigo errado. Nao sei pq raios da esse erro.

Comment: @alessandremartins como está a vunção `Salvar()` em seu controller?

Comment: Celsom, editei o post e coloquei a função salvar

Comment: @alessandremartins Se logo no inicio da função você colocar `console.log('rodou")` ele exibe a mensagem no log?

Comment: Celsom, rodou nao... estou usando o template Altair, e axo é eh problema com o template.

Comment: O formulário e a chamada como expliquei estariam corretos. Provavelmente é alguma coisa que não está vinculando o controller com a view. Tente verificar isso, pois o erro refere-se a algo que não está definido.